# how to draw multiple data highcharts treemap with highcharts-react-official?

Tags: typescript, highcharts, treemap

how to draw treemap with [highcharts-react-official](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-react-official) ?
I'm trying to draw my data in the container which is wrapping my treemap, but at some reason the map doesn't show well.

[image]

this is how my treemap looks like. If the chart gets more data from server, then treemap gets densed so that I can't see the treemap data at all.

To make sure here is the code about my ChartContainer.

```js
const Treemap = () => {
  HighchartsTreemap(Highcharts);
  const { countryData } = useCountryData();

  const options = {
    title: {
      text: "",
    },
    series: [
      {
        type: "treemap",
        layoutAlgorithm: "squarified",
        layoutStartingDirection: "horizontal",
        alternateStartingDirection: true,
        data: [
          { name: "Belgium", value: "1" },
          { name: "Bulgaria", value: "2" },
          { name: "China", value: "8" },

        ],
      },
    ],
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <ChartContainer>
        <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={options} />
      </ChartContainer>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Is there anything that I need to add for the options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in chart options with using `highcharts-react-official`. The only thing that you need to improve is the type of value in data. The `value` needs to be a number, not a string.

```
  series: [{
    ...,
    data: [{
        name: "Belgium",
        value: 1
      },
      {
        name: "Bulgaria",
        value: 2
      },
      {
        name: "China",
        value: 8
      }
    ]
  }]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9dr0xL12/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/treemap

Comment: Thanks! it works well!! I should've care more about data type. thank you!